# Should I filter Backend data before displaying or just select the fields and keep the data in memory?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am currently building a FE using jQuery and vanilla JS. I am hitting a Backend API which gives me an array of approx `14000` objects. Each object has `26` fields.

Currently, I am getting the objects and displaying `4` keys out of `26`.

Since I don't have control over the backend, my question is whether is it a good practice and if it's faster to create a new array of those `14000` objects with `4` keys each, and then display them? Which means that I will be discarding the big array `14000` objects with `26` keys for an object and replacing it with an array of `14000` objects with `4` keys for an object.

Any constructive help / comments are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Does the backend implement pagination?

Comment: @kemicofaghost No, it doesn't. It gives 14000 objects in one request.

Comment: I think the problem is more than 14000 records than the number of keys in each object. You need some server-side pagination / filtering. I can't think of a use case where you'd ever need that many records in the UI at once, no human could ever process that volume of info at one go, and it is also quite likely to slow down the JS having to process it for display. Copying from one array to another (even if you discard info along the way), is unlikely to improve the loading time (although of course you could always just test it and see...)!

Comment: @ADyson, It's part of a challenge on how to handle massive amounts of data. I have used infinite scrolling to make the FE user friendly. I am just wondering what is a better way to handle such a scenario.

Comment: Then I would either create a proxy server that would get the 14k objects and implement pagination, or I would just keep the 14k objects in memory and be done with it.

Comment: I think first you need to try it out and see if you really have a genuine performance problem when implementing whatever UI you need. Then if there's really a specific problem you can identify, look at the things kemicofa has suggested - proxying, caching the data, implementing pagination of your own, etc. It's hard for us to suggest solutions where there's no hard-and-fast issue being reported.

Comment: I guess I will keep it as it is. Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: @ADyson since they're using jquery and not some heavy client side framework, I'd reckon that the 14k objects might not be much of  a problem. What's the data size being returned by the backend api (in Mo)?

Comment: @kemicofaghost, The network tab shows 562kB transferred over network.

Comment: Unlikely to cause performance issues even if you implement a loop with low complexity.